# Can Rest web services be used via HTTPS?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

#### I faced an interview question ?

Can we call a REST Webservice through HTTPS? If Yes then How?

I ready don't know answer of this question? Please provide me all Details with an example for IPhone application?

Comment: FYI I don't think you're getting down voted for the question. It is because you want "all Details with an example for iPhone".

Comment: It's the same as with HTTP. Apple provides extensive documentation and sample apps on this exact subject.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, REST can be implemented with HTTPS. There is nothing particularly special about adding SSL to HTTP. Just change the protocol to `https` and be aware that the default port is 443.

Comment: +1 but in short: it works just as with http :)

Comment: please can you provide me an example for IPhone application.

Comment: @Mukesh do you have a REST api already that's working via http?

Comment: @Hackmodford My Main concern is that.

Comment: @Mukesh so no REST api?

Comment: @Mukesh Basically, as long as your server can respond to https requests, you can change your code on the iPhone to use https instead of http.

Comment: @Hackmodford My Main concern is that<br/> I am using THis [basic links](http://xxx.xxx.xx.xx:xxxx/webservices/… ). `code+(NSURLRequest *) a:(NSString *)a groupID:(NSString *)b{ NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@report.php?email=%@&group_id=%@",GLOBALPATH,[a convertEntities],[b convertEntities]]; NSURLRequest *requestULR=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[urlString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]]; return requestULR; }`